# Is $\ell_1$ regularization not compatible with SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, lasso, regularization

In the notes of Andrew Ng's CS229 Machine Learning course, it is mentioned:

> The $\ell_2$ norm regularization is
> much more commonly used with kernel methods because $\ell_1$ regularization is
> typically not compatible with the kernel trick.

Knowing that Lasso regression can lead to sparse models where many parameters are updated to 0, and knowing that SVM (which uses the kernel trick for linearly non-separable cases) benefits from sparsity of non-zero $\alpha$ parameters, I wonder if the above statement implies that $\ell_1$ regularization is considered incompatibile with SVM as well.
Or is it that the regularization used in SVM's soft margin is neither Lasso, nor Ridge, because it involves a different "slack variable", not the actual $\alpha$ parameters?

My intuition tells me that the sparsity of support vectors is a consequence of the SMO algorithm, not of the regularization per se, and the regularization itself is neither Ridge, nor Lasso. If my intuition is not correct, can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: The sparsity of the SVM is a fortunate by-product, and if you tune the hyper-parameters well, the sparsity often diminishes.  If you want a sparse model, use a model that is designed to promote sparsity.  The sparsity of the SVM is independent of the training algorithm, it is a consequence of the form of the optimisation problem, the optimality conditions (the KKT conditions) for which imply sparsity.

Comment: If you have an infinite dimensional feature space, such as that induced by the radial basis function kernel, you would need an infinite length vector to represent which primal parameters were zero.  You could use the hinge loss and an L1 penalty on the "dual" parameters, but then it would no longer be a kernel model as the interpretation of a model built in a fixed feature space would no longer hold - but it would be an L1 regularised RBF neural network - there is nothing wrong with that!